# LatentDirichletAllocation python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda

I am using following code for LatentDirichletAllocation  through scikit of python library:

```
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2, stop_words='english')
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=10, max_iter=5, 
learning_method='online', learning_offset=50.,random_state=0).fit(tf)
lda_W = lda_model.transform(tf)
lda_H = lda_model.components_
```

when I print shape of lda_H it returns (10, 236), I understand 10 is for topic numbers and 236 are the words. I wish to see the effect of alpha on this so i changed the above code to :

```
lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=10,doc_topic_prior=.01, max_iter=5, 
learning_method='online', learning_offset=50.,random_state=0).fit(tf)
lda_W = lda_model.transform(tf)
lda_H = lda_model.components_
```

however i found there is no effect of alpha on the words in the Topics and  lda_H still returns (10, 236). I wonder why alpha does not change the words in the topic. i tried different values of the alpha but no changed is observed in lda_H 
Please any comments on it is appreciated.

Comment: Whats the value of `no_topics`?

Comment: no_topics=10 and also the number of the features are 236

Comment: Your `lda_H` will always have 236 features as they are the sent by the CountVectorizer into it. `doc_topic_prior` will not change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha is a parameter that controls the shape of the per-document topic distributions and does not influence the number of topics. The number of topics is not inferred, but fixed a priori by `no_topics`.

Each document is always a mixture distribution over all topics, and alpha controls the distribution of probabilities over all topics for each document. We can set it according to whether we a priori expect each document to be a relatively even mixture over all topics, or whether we expect the majority of the probability to be allocated to a smaller set of topics per document.

The changes with alpha should reflect in the return from the `transform` call, which you have assigned to `lda_W`. This gives the matrix of per-document topic distributions. It will still be the same shape: `(n_samples, n_topics)`, but you should see changes in the average spread of probabilities for each row (document). You could measure this, for instance, by setting a threshold probability and checking the number of topics per document which exceed this probability, averaged across all documents, comparing for the two values of alpha.

The topic distribution is also inferred as a mixture distribution over all words, so the number of words won't change, but rather the probability allocated to each word per topic.

It's well worth giving the [original paper on LDA](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf) a read for a more in-depth explanation of what the algorithm is doing.

Comment: thanks. From your comments above, I have developed this understanding that alpha will affect the topic distribution in a document. Now my query is, in that case, if change the alpha then which variable should i look in above code to see the effect of the alpha or how I can observe the distribution of the topics in a document.

Comment: Sure thing- I've edited the answer to show how to check the effect of alpha.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear!

Comment: On the same note, I wonder what are your thoughts towards evaluating the LDA, as now I have topics and documents but I wonder other than human analysis is there any machine learning measure to see how result documents fit to the associated topic.